# iPod Nano (7th gen) Bluetooth connection keeps dropping

Tags: bluetooth, ipod-nano

When I use my iPod Nano (7th generation) with SwageU Bluetooth headphones, the connection keeps dropping with a double beep.  Both devices are charged.  I haven't had a problem using these headphones with an iPad.  Which should I blame, the iPod or the headphones?

Comment: Does the iPod work with other Bluetooth headphones?

Comment: @RedEagle2000, I don't know, I don't have any other Bluetooth headphones to try.

Comment: Do you have anything that can be connected by Bluetooth?

Comment: @RedEagle2000, besides the iPod, headphones, and the iPad I mentioned, the only other Bluetooth capable devices I have are a MacBook Pro and an Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First I'd try a simple restart (hold down the sleep/wake button and home button until the screen goes dark and release when you see the Apple logo)
- Unpair the Bluetooth headphones from everything. The manufacturer should have instructions on how to unpair them from everything at once, or you can manually unpair them from all your devices individually.
- Turn Bluetooth off and back on on your iPod.
- Get a $10-$15 Bluetooth speaker from Wal-Mart and see if it will work with your iPod.

Check out this [Apple Support link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203681) for additional help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had already tried step 1, so I tried 1 through 3.  Afterward, I had some trouble getting the iPod to re-pair with the headphones, but after I did, the connection has been solid, even when I walked around the room with the iPod sitting on a table.